# Passing value from previous result python

Tags: python, while-loop, pass-by-reference

I want to evaluate the gap of a variable between time interval.

Here is an example of the calculation:

```
 Count | Gap    |  Gap Result  |  Evaluate
----------------------------------------
  19   | 15-5   |   10         |   10
  18   | 15-3   |   12         |   10-12 = -2
  17   | 15-4   |   11         |   12-11 = 1
```

I have no idea how to express it. Please advice.

```
number = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
goal = 15
count = 20
def step (self)
    while count > 0:
          count -= 1
          gap = [goal - (random.choice(number))]
          previous_gap = gap from (count - 1) # I don't know how to express this
          evaluate = previous_gap - gap
```

Comment: It'd help if you told us what the expected outcome would be. You haven't really defined what you mean by 'gap'?

Comment: Why are you trying to subtract lists? `evaluate = previous_gap - gap`

Comment: @MartijnPieters question edited. Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to store the previous gap too; set it to 0 to start with. You don't want a list, you are dealing with individual numbers here:

```
goal = 15
count = 20
previous_gap = evaluate = 0

while count > 0:
    count -= 1
    gap = goal - random.choice(number)
    if previous_gap:
        evaluate = previous_gap - gap
    # remember the gap for the next step
    previous_gap = gap
```